# How can I disable an anchor until I assign an href attribute value?

Tags: html, jquery

Here I want disable the anchor. While the anchor is in its initial state it should not navigate.

html

```
<a class="link" id="decre" href="" disabled><i class='far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left navigate_arrow'</i</a>
```

JQuery

```
var tNumber = {{ProductDetails.id}};
var count = {{ count }}
var count_classifieds = count + 1
var sSting = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/";

$("#decre").click(function(){
    tNumber--;
    if (tNumber > 0) {
    var cConcate= sSting + tNumber+"/";
    $("#decre").attr("href", cConcate);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no `disabled` attribute on an anchor.

Comment: I've attempted to fix your English. I assume "arrow" meant link or anchor element. Please revise if that's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the question correctly. In this example, I used CSS to deactivate a tag. Because disabled attribute does not work for hyperlink!

```js
var tNumber = {{ ProductDetails.id }};
var count = {{ count }}
var count_classifieds = count + 1
var sSting = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/";

$("#decre").click(function () {
    tNumber--;
    if (tNumber > 0) {
        var cConcate = sSting + tNumber + "/";
        $("#decre").attr("href", cConcate);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

```css
a.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

<a class="disabled" id="decre" href=""><i class='far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left navigate_arrow'></i></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the solution and it was working too. But here i have one issue that is while i am navigating to the ads. The ads which is deleted taking that id and throwing the error i want to skip that id where the ad is deleted

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged this with `jquery`, you could easily disable the default click behavior when the `href` attribute is empty

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href=""]', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">Empty</a>
<a href="">Empty</a>
<a href="">Empty</a>
<a href="">Empty</a>
<a href="#foo">foo</a>
```